# node js mongoose find by deeply nested documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In Node js mongoose Need to search the article description in following schema levels. how can it be possible with mongoose.
I have tried using $elemMatch and its not working. schema level is as follows.

```
var articleSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    displayName: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },

});

mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema);   

var subChapterSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    displayName: {type: String},
    Articles:[articleSchema],


});

mongoose.model('SubChapter', subChapterSchema); 

var chapterSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true },
    displayName: {type: String },
    subChapters: [subChapterSchema],

});

mongoose.model('Chapter', chapterSchema);

var agreementSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true },
    displayName: {type: String },
    Chapters: [chapterSchema],

});

mongoose.model('Agreement', agreementSchema);
```

I have tried as follows.but its not working.

```
var regex = new RegExp(text, "i");

    var criteria = { 
    Chapters.subChapters.Articles : {
                                                    $elemMatch: {
                                                        description:regex
                                                    }
                                                  }
                                        }

Agreement.find({criteria},'name displayName',function(err,docs){
        if (err)
            console.log('error occured in the database');
        console.log(docs);
    });
```

Comment: `subChapters:[chapterSchema]` or `chapters:[chapterSchema]` in `agreementSchema ` ?

Comment: chapters:[chapterSchema]

Comment: remember that `key` is case-sensitive  `chapters` and `Chapters` are different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `$regex` and `$options`.

When your criteria is an object then no need to use `{criteria}` in find just use `find(criteria`.
If `subChapters:[chapterSchema]` in your `agreementSchema` then use `subChapters.subChapters.Articles.description:` in my example used `chapters.subChapters.Articles.description:`.

and you should use `""` when want to find nested field

```
var text = 'search text';

var criteria = {
  "chapters.subChapters.Articles.description": { $regex: text, $options: 'i' }
};

Agreement.find(criteria, 'name displayName', function (err, docs) {
  if (err)
    console.log('error occured in the database');
  console.log(docs);
});
```